# How can I set click function on my current element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to dynamically set a click function on a `role=button` element I add from jQuery. Here is my code:

```
box_resources.forEach(function(box){
  var title_button = '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="margin:5px">' + title + '</a>';
  var $list_item = $(title_button);
  $list_item.click(function() {
    console.log("hello");
  });
  $("#resources-master-list").append(title_button); 
});
```

It seems this way does not work. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: the problem might be that `var $list_item = $(title_button);` is looking for the element to exist on the page. Perhaps do the `append` first, and then add your click handler?

Comment: once the element exists you can add it using document.getElementById( "elemId" ).onclick = function(){ alert( ' stuff is happenin' ) }

Comment: You append the `title_button` string, not the jq object `$list_item`. There is for sure no click event bound to the string... Use `$("#resources-master-list").append($list_item);`

Comment: @A.Wolff That's a good call! I should append the jq object. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a new click handler each time you add an item to the DOM, try using **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**. To understand how this works, check out the link for more information.:

```
$(document).on("click", "[role='button']", function () {
  alert("i'm clicked");
});
```